# Refreshing page after posted vars

Tags: php, html, variables

So a form is submitted on my site, with form action equal to itself.

I want the user to be able to refresh the page without sending the same variables again.

I thought unset($_POST); would accomplish this for some reason it doesn't is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unset($_POST) wont' help you. As this array being populated from the browser request.

The common practice (and protocol requirement) is to use HTTP redirect to some (usually same) location.
A rough outline of a POST form handler in the same file is like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { 
    //write data
    Header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
    exit; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: i can't accept for 7 minutes apparently, but i shall when i can thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may want to tackle this problem by issuing a [server-side redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/301_redirect#Using_server-side_scripting_for_redirection) to a `GET` request, when the `POST` request responds. This will prevent the users from refreshing the page and accidentally resending the `POST` request.

Comment: thanks for your advice Daniel, so do you mean like have form.php and the form_posted.php?

Comment: use the header function to perform this redirect.

Comment: @Pete: Yes. This a popular method to implement the typical `thank_you` page. It is considered good practice to redirect the user to a `thank_you` page generated from a `GET` request, instead of one returned from a `POST` request.